# Sync Third party CRM with Salesforce

Tags: integration, automation, crmfusion

My company has its own Platform that manage most of the data and recenetly we started using Salesforce and it turn out quite good. So for our next step we want to **sync all our Platform data with salesforce.**
What ever we edit or make change on the platform it should automatically populate the predefined fields in Salesforce.

So for that reason i would like to know if there is a way to do this? And if so what is the best program for that? Can somebody provide me with this information?

Thank you for your understanding.

Regards,

Darko

Comment: You can write API's in salesforce and call that api from your application.  - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

Answer (score 1):

There are [different levels of integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integration). This answer focuses on data integration:

**0. App Exchange Plugin**

It is possible that your CRM provider offers a free AppExchange integration solution..

**1. Direct integration**

One solution is that your external application utilizes its ability to make outbound http calls. And inserts or updates data within salesforce using the [rest](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) or [soap](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/) interface of the force.com platform.

The other approach is to use salesforce outbound http calls to extract the data from an external system. (Assume the external system is a public web application and offers REST or SOAP interfaces.)

**2. Integration Plattform**

An integration approach is to utilize salesforce’s new “[lightning connect](http://www.softwareag.com/corporate/Press/pressreleases/20141114_SalesForce_dot_com_page.asp)” system to stream the data from your external application to salesforce. (In this case the data is only displayed inside of salesforce without storing the records there.)

In case you want to import and export data from one system to the other you can choose between different integration applications e.g.:

1. [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/)
2. [WebMethods](http://www.softwareag.com/corporate/products/webmethods_integration/integration/overview/default.asp)
3. [Boomi](http://www.boomi.com/solutions/salesforce)
4. [Informatica](http://www.informaticacloud.com/connectivity/salesforce-connector)

Comment: @ChristianDeckster thank you very much for the detail information. I would not go with the 2.Integration Platform because i really don't want to relay on excel documents.  

1.Direct Integration for me is the best one and as Akash suggested i will need to look into REST and SOAP.

Comment: Darko, why would Option #2 relay on Excel documents? Any of the 4 platforms described above would work without the need to use excel. Those would connect DB to DB, and without you having to write any code.